# How to select an item in ScrollView with SwiftUI?

Tags: foreach, swiftui, scrollview

what I am trying to accomplish is have a loop of items where I am able to tap one and it gets bigger programmatically once tapped

here is my code and my results so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var emojisArray = ["", "", "", ""]
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    ForEach(0..<emojisArray.count) { item in
                        
                        
                        emojiView(emoji: self.emojisArray[item],
                                  isSelected: item == self.selectedIndex ? true : false)
                            
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print (item)
                                self.selectedIndex = item
                                
                                
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        .onAppear()
            .frame(height:160)
            
            VStack{
                Text("selcted item:")
                Text("\(self.emojisArray[self.selectedIndex])")
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

where emojiView is :

```
struct emojiView: View {
    
    var emoji : String
    @State var isSelected : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(emoji)
            .font(isSelected ? .system(size: 120) : .system(size: 45))
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is that the ScrollView does't reload itself

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `@State` in `emojiView`

```
struct emojiView: View {

    var emoji : String
    var isSelected : Bool      // << here !!

    var body: some View {
        Text(emoji)
            .font(isSelected ? .system(size: 120) : .system(size: 45))
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: oh yeah it works but only in the simulator not in the preview, I should have imagine,

Comment: this is not really selecting the element. This is a visual hack to give the impression the element is selected.

Comment: @Duck "selected" doesn't have a universal meaning; it means whatever the designer of the app decides it means. Making the element *look* selected is a perfectly normal, non-hack aspect of what it means to *be* selected